# How to sort some data in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, sql-order-by

I'm using Ruby 1.8.2 and Rails 2.3.11.

```
<% @answered_respondents = Inquiry.find(:all, :conditions => ["question_id = (?) AND is_answered = 1 AND is_denied = 0", q.id]) %>


<% @answered_respondents.each_with_index do |r, i| %>
    <% @nene = Respondent.find(:all, :conditions => ["id = (?)", r.respondent_id ]) %>
      <% @nene.each do |zz| %>
         <span class="statis_answered_resp"><%= zz.email %></span>
      <% end %>
<% end %>
```

What I want to do: I want to sort by email my users (zz.email). How I can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a default scope in your model

```
Rails2:   default_scope :order => 'email ASC' 
Rails3:   default_scope order('email ASC')
```

The default will be just that, the default for all your views.

For other orderings you can also create other scopes, e.g.

```
Rails2:   named_scope :special :order => 'email ASC' 
Rails3:   scope :special order('email ASC')
```

To use therm you just say ModelName.all.special
It would also be a good idea to upgrade your ruby to 1.8.7 at least.

1.9.2 also works well and would be great too
Though not dependent, it's usually used with Rails3